# programming brain teaser

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

Given a programming language where you could make as many variables up as possible and you could only perform these three operators find b-1.

```
a=0;
b++;
loop(c){  // This loop will loop exactly c times

}
```

an example to find the number 2.

```
a = 0;
a ++;
a ++; // 2
```

How would you find b-1, where b is any positive integer? There are no signed numbers in this language.

Comment: Initialize a to 0 and then {increment and test for equality with b-1} in the loop?

Comment: @alancalvitti: There's no test for equality.

Comment: Please don't vandalize questions.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that the trick to this question is that for `c = 0`, `loop(c){}` loops zero times, ie does nothing. Therefore the following program will work:

```
a=0;
c=0;
loop(b){
  loop(c){
    a++;
  }
  c=0;
  c++;
}
```

We end up with `b-1` in `a`.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 0;    
b = 5;   //Random number
c = 0;

loop(b){
  a = c;    
  c ++;    
}

//c holds value 5    
//a holds value 4
```

Comment: You can't use `b = 5`, `a = c`, only setting to zero is allowed.

Comment: @Thomas The statement `b=5` is irrelevant, but the statement `a=c` can easily be replaced by `a=0; loop(c) {a++;}`, making this similar to the other answer but IMO a bit more standard to programmers (it's the same logic used to crawl to the end of a data structure).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to aws's answer, but I found easier to reason about:

```
c=0;
loop(b){
  a=0;
  // at the beginning of the loop, c lags the counter by 1
  loop(c){
    a++;
  }
  // at the end of the loop, c == counter
  // in the last loop, c is set to b but 'a' still lags by 1
  c++;
}
```

This answer is obviously less efficient, looping something like `(b-2) + (b-3) + ... + (b-b)` more times.